# Particle system hairs not in same location as hairs?

Tags: mesh, particles, edges, keyframes, hair

So I set a few trees to a particle group, and I set all the origins of each parent tree to its base:

[image]

However when I add hairs using particle edit the trees are displaced from where the hair was added.

[image]

[image]

File too big for upload but heres a google drive link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AGh2Xbr6MX4PTNnPQe2RWp6zWOMaC70A/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the objects are not at the origo. You have to disable the "Global Coordinates" option in the Particle Render Properties to ignore the location of the trees.

[image]